# Measuring time of execution using multi thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import threading
import time
from pymongo import MongoClient
import gridfs
bridgeVideoDatabase = MongoClient().bridgeVideoDatabase
fs = gridfs.GridFS(bridgeVideoDatabase)

app = Flask(__name__)

host = '10.0.0.23'
port = 8080

client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
db = client.bridgeUserInformationTable



@app.route('/sendUserStringIntData',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getDataFromAndroid():      
    print "Entire Data:",request.form
    UserName = request.form['UserName']
    print UserName
    #insertion
    db.bridgeUsersInfo.insert({"UserName":UserName})
    #display in console
    cursor = db.bridgeUsersInfo.find()
    for document in cursor:
        print(document)
    Thread1 = threading.Thread(target=getDataFromAndroid)

    t=time.time()

    Thread1.start()
    Thread1.join()
    print'Total time for execution :',time.time()-t,'msec'
    return "User Info Saved successfully in Database :-)"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(
        host=host, port=port
        )
```

Above is the script for measuring time for saving data to database using python and inputing from andoid updated. While running the same it is hosting but after saving text it giving error below

```
       * Running on http://10.0.0.23:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
[2016-11-11 11:52:22,136] ERROR in app: Exception on /sendUserStringIntData [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
TypeError: getDataFromAndroid() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
10.0.0.27 - - [11/Nov/2016 11:52:22] "POST /sendUserStringIntData HTTP/1.1" 500
```

How it should be resolved ?

```
 * Running on http://10.0.0.23:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
Entire Data: ImmutableMultiDict([('UserName', u'mahaveer'), ('Age', u'0'), ('Password', u'null')])
mahaveer
{u'UserName': u'mahaveer', u'Age': u'24', u'_id': ObjectId('5825950e0f325f3a30ef7292'), u'Password': u'12345'}
{u'UserName': u'mahaveer', u'_id': ObjectId('582595530f325f3a563681c7')}
Entire Data:Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/cosmitude10/neon/measureMultithread/test.py", line 22, in getDataFromAndroid
    print "Entire Data:",request.form
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 343, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 302, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/globals.py", line 37, in _lookup_req_object
    raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.

 Total time for execution : 0.00076699256897 msec
10.0.0.27 - - [11/Nov/2016 15:24:27] "POST /sendUserStringIntData HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: The error does not look like it is happening on time duration check

Comment: I didnt get what exact that error mean, i am new to python

Comment: Change position your timing process to under flask handler. Your handler is unowned !  Therad not helping you if you call after doing everythigs !

Comment: How it should be done?

Comment: @mad Please check the answer

Comment: Anything wrong in code ?

Comment: Now i getting error like 'RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.'

Answer (score 0):

[therading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects)

```
threading.Thread(group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={})
```

> args is the argument tuple for the target invocation. Defaults to ()

```
t_args = (1)
assert type(t_args) is tuple, "except tuple, get {0}".format(type(t_args))
>>> AssertionError: except tuple, get <class 'int'>

t_args = (request,)
print type(t_args)
>>> <class 'tuple'>

t= threading.Thread(target=getDataFromAndroid, args=t_args)
```

**tuple args =() / list args =[]**
here you can also use partial from functools to call with args

```
class threading.Timer(interval, function, args=[], kwargs={})
threading.Timer(1, partial(your_method, your_arg_a, your_arg_b)).start()
```

---

there is a built-in module called [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html),

> This module provides a simple way to time small bits of Python code.
>   It has both a Command-Line Interface as well as a callable one. It
>   avoids a number of common traps for measuring execution times

```
import timeit
....
start = timeit.default_timer()
t.start()
t.join()
print timit.default_timer - start
```

Comment: Didnt get exact  what i needed

Comment: I am passing values through android, How should i give that passed parameter value to the thread?

Comment: you mean the "request"  parameter?

Comment: yes, How to pass the parameter in thread which im getting from android?

Comment: Getting error as 'RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.'